# Segmentation fault on ffmpeg sws_scale

Tags: c++, c, ffmpeg

I'm trying to convert an AVFrame from a JPEG (YUV pixel format) to an RGB24 format using ffmpeg's `sws_scale` function. I set up the SwsContext as follows:

```
struct SwsContext *sws_ctx = NULL;
    int frameFinished;
    AVPacket packet;
    // initialize SWS context for software scaling
    sws_ctx = sws_getContext(pCodecCtx->width,
        pCodecCtx->height,
        pCodecCtx->pix_fmt,
        pCodecCtx->width,
        pCodecCtx->height,
        AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24,
        SWS_BICUBIC,
        NULL, NULL, NULL
        );
```

And then, I perform the `sws_scale`, with the following command

```
sws_scale(sws_ctx,
          (uint8_t const * const *)pFrame->data,
          pFrame->linesize,
          0,
          pCodecCtx->height,
          pFrameRGB->data,
          pFrameRGB->linesize);
```

which gives me a segfault, though I'm not sure why. I've tried examining the values through prints and the heights and linesizes and everything all appear to have valid values.

Comment: At a first glance everything seems right. Double-check if `pFrame->data` contains 3 planes with YUV (420P?) data, if `pFrameRGB->linesize[0]` is at least 3 times bigger than `pCodecCtx->width`, and if `pFrameRGB->data` contains 1 plane which is at least `pFrameRGB->linesize[0] * pCodecCtx->height` big. If everything seems ok then see if segfault occurs when reading value or when writing (at least you'll know if it's source or destination frame).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone who comes on this in the future, my issues was that I was not properly initalizing `pFrame` and `pFrameRGB`. The memory first has to be allocated for the frame struct using `av_frame_alloc()`, then the data buffers must be allocated with `av_image_alloc()`.

Comment: Do you happen to know what `sws` stands for?

Comment: @zanbri I'm afraid I don't, sorry!

Comment: SoftWare Scale I think.

Comment: And it corresponds to the hardware scale